# Resonance structure with allylic lone pair

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, resonance, amines, amino-acids

> Draw the appropriate resonance structure for 5-aminolevulinic acid:
>
> [image: 5‐amino‐4‐oxopentanoic acid]

As there is an allylic lone pair, my first arrow goes from the lone pair to form a π-bond, and the second goes from the π-bond to form a lone pair:

[image: My answer]

However, the solution selected a allylic lone pair in a different location in the molecule:

> [image: Solution]

Is my answer also correct? If not, how would I choose the correct lone pair?

Comment: There's no "allylic lone pair" in there! It's a ketone not enol or enolate, or whatever you imagine.

Comment: Draw the hydrogen atoms and see what happens. If you add a proton (that carries the positive charge you have drawn), you would have a valid ionic resonance structure; one that's usually taken to explain hyperconjugation.